# Is it possible to nest foreach loops in Asp.NET razor code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code in which I would like to have an inner foreach loop, but the code doesn't compile with the addition of the inner loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
foreach (var answer in q.Answers)
{
    <input type="checkbox" name="AnswerDetails" value="@answer.AnswerText" data-answerid="@answer.Id">@answer.AnswerText<br />

    foreach (var research in @answer.ResearchSet)
    {
       @:<p>@research.Image</p>
    }
}
```

Comment: you are missing `@` razor symbol at outer `foreach` loop

Comment: also, you did not close your input tag properly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@foreach (var answer in q.Answers)
{
    <input type="checkbox" name="AnswerDetails" value="@answer.AnswerText" data-answerid="@answer.Id" />@answer.AnswerText<br />

    foreach (var research in answer.ResearchSet)
    {
       <p>@research.Image</p>
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sergey, I've tried your suggestion but it didn't work for me. Would you be able to take a look at the code sample below and tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: else if (q.QuestionFormat == QuestionFormatType.multiChoiceMultiAnswer)
                          {
                              @:<form action="#" class="submissionForm" data-questionid="@q.Id" data-questionformat="@q.QuestionFormat">
@foreach (var answer in q.Answers)
{
    <input type="checkbox" name="AnswerDetails" value="@answer.AnswerText" data-answerid="@answer.Id" />@answer.AnswerText<br />

    foreach (var research in answer.ResearchSet)
    {
       <p>@research.Image</p>
    }
}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Answer</button>
    @:</form>

Comment: I've got it working Sergey, thank you for your help.

Comment: @AndreLashley sorry Andre, was AFK. Glad you have solved problem! Btw consider to create form with `Html.BeginForm()`. Also you need `@:` if you are mixing code and plain text. If you have html tags, Razor is pretty clever to define where code ends and tag starts